3 tangential circles in TikZ
How to draw this picture in TikZ or tkz-euclide?

I draw this, but my circle centers are vertices of right triangle.
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=162,scale=1]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){X}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,3){Y}
    \tkzDefPoint(-4,0){Z}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,1){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(-1,0){B}
    
    \tkzDrawCircle[very thick, color=red](X,A)
    \tkzDrawCircle[very thick, color=red](Y,A)
    \tkzDrawCircle[very thick, color=red](Z,B)
    
    \tkzInterCC(Y,A)(Z,B)
    \tkzGetPoints{C}{2}
    
    \tkzInterLC(A,B)(Y,A)
    \tkzGetPoints{e2}{D}
    \tkzInterLC(A,B)(Z,B)
    \tkzGetPoints{E}{e3}
    \tkzInterLC(D,C)(Z,B)
    \tkzGetPoints{e4}{F}
    
    \tkzDrawPolygon[thick,dashed](X,Y,Z)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](D,E,F)
    \tkzDrawSegments[thick,dashed](D,Y Z,F)
    
    \tkzLabelPoint[above left,fill=white](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above left,fill=white](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](C){$C$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[left](D){$D$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above right](E){$E$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[right](F){$F$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](X){$X$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[](Y){$Y$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[](Z){$Z$}
    
    \tkzLabelCircle[above=0.1](X,A)(180){$S_1$}
    \tkzLabelCircle[below=0.1](Y,A)(180){$S_2$}
    \tkzLabelCircle[below=0.5](Z,B)(180){$S_3$}
    
    \tkzDrawPoints[](X,Y,Z,A,B,C,D,E,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

For any three circles, one can locate A, B and C.  A and B give you D and E, D and C give you F.  We can choose the three centers of the circles and solve for the rad'i.  Three equations and three unknonws.

As the others said, we don't even know what your problem is. Drawing circles and lines with a few letters in TikZ shouldn't be a problem. One of TikZ's manual's tutorial can give you a starting help. If you need to find a circle or the points … that's a math problem (which can be solved inside TeX/TikZ if needed).

Change your question, otherwise I think the question will be closed.

Your question is rather incomplete, and I concur with the various remarks that have been made to you. There are two aspects to your question: one is mathematical, and the other concerns the means to draw the figure.
Regarding the mathematical part, you need to specify the data and show what you have done to solve the problem. In the proposed solution, I took the triangle DEF and points A and C as given data.
As for how to draw this figure, it is possible to use TikZ, but since this figure is related to geometry, tkz-euclide seems more appropriate. tkz-elements, based on Lua, allows for even simpler results with a lualatex compilation (see the next TUGboat for a presentation of this package). The drawings are ultimately obtained with tkz-euclide.
For your next questions, you'll need to show what you've tried ...
Update :
Perhaps a solution to get the right figure.
First, we give the triangle IJK formed by the centres of the circles. The tangent circles pass through the points of the contact triangle (refer to MathWorld). Then it's easy to get D, E and F.
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\begin{document}
  
\begin{tkzelements}
   scale       = 1.5
   z.I         = point : new (0,0)
   z.J         = point : new (3,0)
   z.K         = point : new (.5,2)
   T.IJK       = triangle : new (z.I,z.J,z.K)
   T.ABC       = T.IJK : contact ()
   z.A,z.B,z.C = get_points(T.ABC)
   L.AB        = line : new (z.A,z.B)
   C.IC        = circle : new (z.I,z.C)
   _,z.D       = intersection (L.AB,C.IC)
   C.JC        = circle : new (z.J,z.C)
   z.E         = intersection (L.AB,C.JC)
   L.DC        = line : new (z.D,z.C)
   _,z.F       = intersection (L.DC,C.JC)
\end{tkzelements}
  
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzGetNodes
   \tkzDrawPolygons(D,E,F)
   \tkzDrawPolygons[red](I,J,K)
   \tkzDrawCircles[cyan,fill=cyan!10,opacity=.4](I,C)
   \tkzDrawCircles[purple,fill=purple!10,opacity=.4](K,A)
    \tkzDrawCircles[orange,fill=orange!10,opacity=.4](J,C)
   \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,E,F,I,J,K)
   \tkzLabelPoints(A,C,D,F,I,J)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above](B,E,K)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


First wrong solution
A few comments on the following code. For the tkz-elements part, the initial points are defined, then using an "object" design, we create straight lines, triangles and circles.
L.DEis a line through D and E
T.DAC is the triangle defined by the points D,A and C.
C.JC is a circle with center J through C. etc.
Then the macro  \tkzGetNodes in the tikzpicture part, is used to create nodes that can be used with either TikZ or tkz-euclide.
Important Remark : The result is wrong because the circles with centres I and J are not tangent at C. That's why you need to complete your question!
What is the data? Here I'm giving you the means to construct a figure, but first you have a geometric problem to solve.
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[mini]{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\begin{document}
  
\begin{tkzelements}
   scale          = 2
   z.D            = point : new (0,0)
   z.F            = point : new (7,0)
   z.E            = point : new (5,3)
   L.DE           = line : new (z.D,z.E)
   L.FD           = line : new (z.F,z.D)
   z.A            = L.DE : point (0.3)
   z.C            = L.FD : point (0.6)
   T.DAC          = triangle : new (z.D,z.A,z.C)
   T.CEF          = triangle : new (z.C,z.E,z.F)
   z.I            = T.DAC.circumcenter
   z.J            = T.CEF.circumcenter
   C.JC           = circle : new (z.J,z.C)
   _,z.B          = intersection(C.JC,L.DE)
   L.IA           = line : new (z.I,z.A)
   L.JB           = line : new (z.J,z.B)
   z.K            = intersection (L.IA,L.JB)
\end{tkzelements}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzGetNodes
   \tkzDrawPolygons(D,E,F)
   \tkzDrawPoints(I,J,K,A,...,F)
   \tkzDrawCircles(I,D J,C K,A)
   \tkzLabelPoints[above](D,E,F,A,C,B)
   \tkzDrawLines(I,K J,K)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



OK, it's not that simple, but it's a good exercise to remind you of some of Tikz's features.
I haven't detailed the code, I'll let you search (a little) in the documentation and discover the power of Tikz.
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red,name path=Cred] (0,0) coordinate(C1) circle (4cm);
\path (C1) --++ (150:7cm) coordinate (C2);
\draw[blue,name path=Cblue] (C2) circle (3cm);
\draw[dashed,brown,name path=Cc1] (C1) circle (6cm);
\draw[dashed,brown,name path=Cc2] (C2) circle (5cm);
\path [name intersections={of=Cc1 and Cc2}];
\draw[green,name path=Cgreen] (intersection-1) circle (2cm);
%\draw[purple] (intersection-2) circle (2cm);

\path[name intersections={of=Cgreen and Cblue,by=A}];
\node[above]at(A) {A};
\path[name intersections={of=Cred and Cgreen,by=B}];
\node[above] at (B) {B};
\path[name intersections={of=Cblue and Cred,by=C}];
\node[below] at (C) {C};

\draw [dashed,name path=D1] (A) -- (B) coordinate[pos=4](ff) coordinate[pos=-3] (dd)--(ff)--(dd);
\path [name intersections={of=D1 and Cblue}];
\coordinate (D) at (intersection-2);
\path [name intersections={of=D1 and Cred}];

\coordinate (E) at (intersection-2) ;
\draw[thick,black] (D)node[above]{D}-- (E)node[above]{E};

\draw[dashed,name path=D2] (D) -- (C) coordinate[pos=3] (ff) --(ff);
\path [name intersections={of=D2 and Cred}];
\coordinate (F) at (intersection-2);
\draw [thick] (D) -- (F)node[below]{F} --(E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Sorry, but the figure is not correct. C is not the point of tangency between the two circles. C must be the intersection of the circles red and blue and C must be a point of (DF) !
